# How to bucket tables using AWS Glue and Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I am trying to run this query on AWS Glue

```
CREATE TABLE bucketing_example
  USING parquet
  CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 2 BUCKETS
  LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/bucketing_example'
  AS SELECT * FROM (
   VALUES(1, 'red'),
         (2, 'orange'),
         (5, 'yellow'),
         (10, 'green'),
         (11, 'blue'),
         (12, 'indigo'),
         (20, 'violet'))
   AS Colors(id, value)
```

and I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:163)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:175)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.CatalogUtils$.stringToURI(ExternalCatalogUtils.scala:236)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getDatabase$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:343)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getDatabase$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:339)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
```

Also, I tried to run a Spark SQL query similar to [these](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5297096877265087/408112371708998/6239976614347962/latest.html) on a bucketed table that was created using Athena (still using Glue).

Although the a `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` on the table reveals the bucket column, the Exchanges on the arms of the JOIN remain in the plan.

Does bucketing work with Glue and Spark SQL?

Comment: Have you tried passing s3 location to your create table statement ?

Comment: yes, that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

"To leverage bucketed tables within Athena, you must use Apache Hive to create the data files because Athena does not support the Apache Spark bucketing format"

seealso: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/

Hive bucketing write support - target version 3.2.0
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19256